# I may have gotten a virus on my desktop how do I completely remove all possible bad things?

Tags: windows-7

So basically I’m using an old computer and I visited a site that may have given me a virus so I did some kind of wiping on my computer and restarted it, is there a way to completely remove all viruses and stuff like that so I can be confident nothing bad is on my computer?  My processor is pentium and I’m running windows 7.